# Redirect Loop on Drupal 6 after moving website

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, mamp, redirect-loop

I posted a question earlier today asking which files needed to be changed to move drupal to MAMP successfully.

I've now moved it all over and connected it to the database, however, I'm stuck in a redirect loop whilst trying to view the website. As far as I can gather, the redirect loop is stuck between index.php and install.php

How do I fix this? What would cause a redirect loop?

I read somewhere that there was a redirect file in a tmp directory and removing it will solve the issue, but for me the file doesn't exist.

Comment: A redirect loop sometimes occur if the install.php file is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my own in-experience with Drupal, I failed to recognise that the site in question was a Drupal Multi-site. The sites folder contained 'all' and 'example.com' There was no 'default' folder.

There was two solutions to my issue.

1. Set up MAMP as a Virtual Host (so example.com would direct to my mamp installation and so tick all the boxes for the files redirection)
2. Change the folder name to 'localhost' and not 'example.com'

The second solution did leave me with one or two issues, but as I'm only needing this installation for the theme I decided a botched solution would be least time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your web server has read permissions for `settings.php`.

Also check if the database is set up properly. As always, [drush](http://drush.ws/) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an `.htaccess` issue, this happens sometimes when you're moving the site from a root path (ie. example.com/) to a subfolder (ie. localhost:8888/drupal/).

Try changing the `RewriteBase` in the `.htaccess` file to:

```
RewriteBase /drupal/
```

Where `drupal` is the name of the subfolder Drupal is installed in.

Comment: Going for a double whammy? Unfortunately this didn't work. I added the line to the .htaccess file (or rather, uncommented out the drupal provided one and modified to match foldernames) but no luck, I still get a redirect loop.